# What happened to the other 9 astronauts?

Tags: plot-explanation, interstellar

In the beginning of the mission, it's mentioned that 12 pioneers went out to try to find a new world for humanity. During the duration of the film, they only visit 3 of those 12 planets and respective astronauts. What happened to the other 9? Did they communicate back to NASA that their planet was inhospitable?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since only one system with 3 worlds show promise, we can infer that the other 9 astronauts are dead. Either they didn't make it to their worlds or they landed on uninhabitable worlds.

> PROFESSOR BRAND
>
> Twelve possible worlds. Twelve
> Ranger launches carrying the
> bravest humans ever to live, led by
> the remarkable Dr Mann.
>
> DOYLE
>
> Each person’s landing pod had life
> support for two years - but they
> could use hibernation to stretch
> that, making observations on
> organics over a decade or more.
> Their mission was to assess their
> world, and if it showed promise,
> send a signal, bed down for the
> long nap, and wait to be rescued.
>
> COOPER
>
> And if their world didn’t show
> promise?
>
> DOYLE
>
> Hence the bravery.
>
> COOPER
>
> Because you don’t have resources to
> visit all twelve.
>
> DOYLE
>
> No. Data transmission back through
> the wormhole is rudimentary, simple
> binary ’pings’ on an annual basis
> to give some clue as to which
> worlds have potential. One system
> shows promise.
>
> COOPER
>
> One? Kind of a long shot.
>
> BRAND
>
> One system with three potential
> worlds ... no long shot.

Full script [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4C9FN_1M1sxVFpHRTlaYmxSdzA/view?pli=1)

Comment: Well at the very least this system showed the most promise with 3 potential colony worlds.  With only one Endurance ship they have to choose the most likely destination.

Comment: That is a good point. It is possible one of the other 9 did manage to land on a habitable planet, but since they where never 'rescued' by the Endurance crew, they would have eventually run out of supplies and died.

Comment: Wow, I must have missed that third line of Doyle's the two times I watched this film. I guess that papers over some of the plot holes, though maybe not really. Did that line actually make it into the film?

Comment: @Muzer: Yes, I watched it a week ago and it was there.